# URL Redirect Not Working

Tags: url

Seems like I can't get the base install URL to work. To get Craft to show posts I have to format the URL as,

```
/public/index.php?p=news/2015/we-just-installed-craft
```

Instead of just the `/news/2015/we-just-installed-craft`

I think the `.htaccess` is getting read because after putting in garbage the server did error out when I used the /public/ URL but not sure what else I'm doing wrong or how I could troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting ['usePathInfo' => true](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#usePathInfo) and ['omitScriptNameInUrls' => true](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#omitScriptNameInUrls) in your `craft/config/general.php` file.

Comment: Got it, that worked. I moved the public files out to the my main server folder getting rid of the /public/ string, so that was the last piece I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue and got it fixed by doing the following

Note: I am using Ubuntu

1. Assume `apache2` is installed
2. Run `sudo a2enmod rewrite`
3. Ensure `Options FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch` is within your virtualhost `<directory>` config
4. Run `sudo service apache2 restart`

Hope this helps!